# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in ajax api

Tags: javascript

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost./panel/app/funcs/user/normal_user_funcs.php' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

js.js

[image]

php.php
[image]

Comment: you should probably add the header(...) in index.php

Comment: _not present on the **requested resource**._ not ***requesting resource***

Answer (score -2):

replace your header with the following in normal_user_funcs.php :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

Comment: Not work.     Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost./panel/app/funcs/user/normal_user_funcs.php' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.